# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_theme_support' (T_STRING) in16

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to share Functions.php all code here, here is the error message `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_theme_support' (T_STRING) in /home/autocara/public_html/wp-content/themes/leadgenthemev3bannerfix/functions.php on line 16"`
 someone to say where is the problem specifically.

```
<?php load_theme_textdomain('text_domain'); ?>
<?php


    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true );
    add_image_size( 'single-post-thumbnail', 300, 9999 );

    automatic_feed_links();

    function removeHeadLinks() {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
     }
    add_action('init', 'removeHeadLinks');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
    if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Sidebar Widgets',
            'id'   => 'sidebar-widgets',
            'description'   => 'These are widgets for the sidebar.',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h4>',
            'after_title'   => '</h4>'
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Is this the whole file? Line 16 in your error message may differ from line 16 in your pasted code.